# Microsoft Office 2013 emails copied to folder show in deleted items folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, user-folders

**Microsoft Office 2013 emails copied to folder show in deleted items:** folder:

It seems that when I move my emails from my Inbox to a sub-folder of the same Inbox folder [that is, for my own instance of Outlook email] (say "folder1") in Outlook, they apparently **also get copied** to the "Deleted Items" folder as well as "folder1".

This is somewhat annoying, as it alarms me to think that they have disappeared, but they still seem to be in "folder1" ....

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  I just want to validate that I am not 'losing' important emails.  (They would still be recoverable).

Comment: What accounts do you have installed in Outlook? Who are the providers?

Comment: Its provided by my organization; typically I am the only user of this instance of Outlook, however.

Comment: Ok. But what accounts do you have installed? Is it a company email box - is it on Exchange is in Office 365? Any other accounts? Is the problem occurring in a specific email box? Please clarify if you are just moving the message from your inbox to a sub folder of the same inbox - noting that the inbox is it’s own folder in your mailbox - I am not referring to a sub folder in some other part of your mailbox.

Comment: The subfolder is indeed a subfolder of Inbox, I edited the question to emphasize that.  It is (as far as I know) an Outlook folder and not directly tied to my workstation, though for all I know there could be a mirror folder on my workstation or some virtual entity.

Comment: How did you move the email? Did you manually drag&drop it? Is this issue replicable if we test it within OWA? AFAIK, this is not a normal behavior in Outlook. I'd recommend you start Outlook in safe mode (outlook.exe /safe) and see whether this issue continues.

Comment: @Steve Fan: I don't think it would be repeatable, as it is probably system dependent.  If you want to 'promote' part of your comment [about 'normal behavior'] to an answer, I will accept it.